# issues in Cisco 2960

Tags: networking, snmp, ethernet, cisco

I can get the switch status by using  `oid : .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8`

*This displays all the ports with status up or down.*

However, I want an `oid` to check the particular port, e.g. to check whether the 5th port is up or down.

Also, I want an `oid` to get the MAC Address & IP which is connected to a port, e.g. the MAC Address & IP of a PC which is connected to port 5.

Comment: There is an answer on ServerFault that may help you: http://serverfault.com/questions/207768/dell-switch-6248-port-and-mac-mapping-using-snmp

Answer (score 0):

The data about ports is stored in a MIB table. The table OID is `.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1`, which means, that to get a specific piece of data you must query:

```
.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.X.Y
```

where `X` is the item index, and `Y` is the port index. For example the oid for the description of port 10101 is `.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.10101`:

```
$ snmpget -mall -v1 -c public <switch_ip> .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.10101    
IF-MIB::ifDescr.10101 = STRING: GigabitEthernet0/1
```

To get all the data in the ports table you can query it like this:

```
$ snmpwalk -mall -v1 -c public <switch_ip> .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1
```

To get MAC addresses on a specific port you can query the FDB in BRIDGE-MIB:

```
$ snmpwalk -mall -v1 -c public <switch_ip> .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.2
```

Since switching on 2960 is mostly a layer 2 operation, there is no way to get the corresponding IP addresses, unless you set it up as router.

Comment: at wroniasty,

i have tried `snmpwalk -mall -v1 -c public <switch_ip> .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.2`, but still am not getting any results, please help me

i have doubt that, where i am specifying my port no. ?

Comment: are you replacing `<switch_ip>` and `public` with the right values? are there any entries in the FDB on the switch?

Comment: yes, i am changing `<switch_ip>` to my switch ip,

i have entries like his `SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.2.232.57.53.88.249.158 = INTEGER: 5`
still more entries,
i am running this query in Red Hat Terminal,

Comment: this is the FDB, the last 6 numbers in the OID is the MAC, the `INTEGER: 5` is the port number where the MAC was last seen.

Comment: you mean to say `249.158` is the MAC ???

i have connected a PC to port 2,5,7 am getting the result only for the port 5,

what about the rest....?

Comment: `232.57.53.88.249.158` is actually `e8:39:35:58:f9:9e`. is there any traffic on ports 2,7? FDB entries usually timeout and are removed after a while of inactivity

Comment: i am using Cisco Catalyst 2960 Switch Series SI,

there no traffic at all on ports 2,7
this system are not inactivity, i am using them.....

i have swing front end, with a button,
when a 1st button is clicked,i want to show a mac of a specific port,

how to convert `232.57.53.88.249.158` to `e8:39:35:58:f9:9e`,
such a way that when a button is clicked, `e8:39:35:58:f9:9e` is displayed......?